How to implement Entra ID External authentication method with AD FS
Microsoft is introducing External authentication ID (currently in preview) in Entra and points out that the external provider is to be implemented over OID Connect.
Following this, I assume we can use an AD FS server as an OIDC endpoint, serving as External authentication ID provider. There are plenty of tutorials on how to create an OIDC endpoint in ADFS.
What I cannot understand, is how to connect the two together: the configuration page for the External authentication method is asking for data not available in OIDC, like App ID, also I see that the shared secret is missing and what is now known, is the relaying party ID to be entered in AD FS.
Can anyone shed the light on how to bring about this configuration?

currently in preview typically for products that are still vapor, the best contact is the vendor.
